# How to implement my validation, through jquery validation plugin? I am not able to validate my form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is my HTML page..

```
<div>
<form id="signupForm" method="get" action="">
<table> 
  <tr><td><input type="button" value="New" onclick="clearuserfields()"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td>USERID:</td><td><input type="text" id="userID"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td>FNAME:</td><td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>LNAME:</td><td><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>EMAIL:</td><td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>PASSWORD:</td><td><input type="text" id="password" name="password" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>PHONENO:</td><td><input type="text" id="phoneno" name="phoneno" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>ROLL:</td><td><input type="text" id="roll" name="roll" /></td></tr>
 <td><input type="button" value="Save" onclick="initialiseusers()"/></td>
 <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteuser()"/></td> 
 </table>
 </form>
</div>
this is my JS page
function initialiseusers(){
$("#signupForm").validate({
    rules: {
        fname: "required",
        lname: "required",
        email:{
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        phoneno:"required",
        roll:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },      
        messages: {
            fname:"Please enter your firstname",
            lname:"Please enter your lastname",
            email:"Please enter a valid email address",
            password:{
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            phoneno:"Please enter your phoneno",
            roll:"Please enter your role"
        }
    }
         updateusers();// when the validation is over this function being called for updating the user.
});
```

But the validation is not working and when i click the save button.It directly  saves Blank values inside my DB I downloaded the validation plugin and added it in the path also.,Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation plugin binds to the form's `submit` event, it's not meant to be called in-line.  Instead setup the validation, then call [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to check it, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#signupForm").validate({
    rules: {
        fname: "required",
        lname: "required",
        email:{
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        phoneno:"required",
        roll:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        }
    },      
    messages: {
        fname:"Please enter your firstname",
        lname:"Please enter your lastname",
        email:"Please enter a valid email address",
        password:{
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },
        phoneno:"Please enter your phoneno",
        roll:"Please enter your role"
    }
  });
});
function initialiseusers(){
  if($("#signupForm").valid())
    updateusers(); //called if successfully validated
}
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BSmVv/),  [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) **sets up** the validation, it doesn't execute it, [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) does, and returns a boolean of if it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the validate plugin works, but you may need to return "false" from initialiseusers in order to prevent the default form submission from happening.